# Prove $\int^{n+1}_1\frac{1}{x} dx \leq 1 + 1/2 + \cdots + 1/n$.

Tags: integration, riemann-sum

> Source: [https://math.mit.edu/~choiks/Pset%202%20solutions.pdf](https://math.mit.edu/%7Echoiks/Pset%202%20solutions.pdf)
>
> [image: proof]

I don't understand the third line $\int^{n+1}_1\frac{1}{x}dx  \leq 1 + 1/2 + \cdots + 1/n$.

I think it should rather be $\int^{n+1}_1\frac{1}{x}dx  \geq 1 + 1/2 + \cdots + 1/n$ because

$\int^{n}_1\frac{1}{x} < \int^{n+1}_1\frac{1}{x}$ and $1 + 1/2 + \cdots + 1/n$ is just addition of $f(x) = 1/x$ at certain values (integers). Therefore:

$1 + 1/2 + \cdots + 1/n < \int^{n}_1\frac{1}{x} < \int^{n+1}_1\frac{1}{x}$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Consider this example:

$A_i =$ the area under $\frac 1x$ from $x=1$ to $x=3$. $A_a =$ the area of the width-$1$ rectangle, with its base on the $x$-axis, and its upper-left corner on the point $(1,1)$, plus the area of the width-$1$ rectangle, with its base on the $x$-axis, and its upper-left corner on the point $(2,\frac 12)$.

Certainly (and this may be clearer if you draw the rectangles on the curve) we have $A_i < A_a$. That is, $\int_0^{2+1} \frac 1x dx < 1 + \frac 12$. Loosely speaking, this is because the two rectangles together a) cover up the entire area enclosed by $y=\frac 1x,y=0,x=1,x=3$, and then have some 'area left over.' Indeed, these estimations with rectangles are *[left Riemann sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Left_Riemann_sum)*, which are overestimations if you use them to estimate functions which are monotonic decreasing on an interval. The link provided has better (visual!) examples.

In this case, this generalizes to $\int_1^{n+1} \frac 1x dx < \sum_{k <n+1} \frac 1k$ for $n \geq 1$, which is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_1^{n+1}\dfrac{1}{x}\mathrm dx=\sum_{k=1}^n\int_k^{k+1}\dfrac{1}{x}\mathrm dx$$
$$<\sum_{k=1}^n\int_k^{k+1}\dfrac{1}{k}\mathrm dx$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{1}{k}$$
Similarly, you use $$\sum_{k=1}^n\int_k^{k+1}\dfrac{1}{x}\mathrm dx>\sum_{k=1}^n\int_k^{k+1}\dfrac{1}{k+1}\mathrm dx$$
to get the other bound.

Answer (score 1):

There are simple diagrams that compare sums and integrals.... Here what I call $f(x)$ is real valued and continuous, also positive. Things change (order of the inequalities) depending on $f$ increasing or decreasing. I guess $a < b$ are fixed integers.

if we have $f(x) > 0$ and $f'(x) > 0,$  then
$$ \int_{a-1}^{b} \; f(x) \;  dx \;  < \; \sum_{j=a}^b \;  f(j) \; < \; \int_{a}^{b+1} \;  f(x) \; dx   $$

if we have $f(x) > 0$ but $f'(x) < 0,$  then
$$ \int_a^{b+1} \; f(x) \;  dx \;  < \; \sum_{j=a}^b \;  f(j) \; < \; \int_{a-1}^b \;  f(x) \; dx   $$
 We use this second one, as we are going to integrate $1/x$ we take $a=2$ along with $b=n$
$$ \int_2^{n+1} \; \frac{1}{x} \;  dx \;  < \; \sum_{j=2}^n \;  \frac{1}{j} \; < \; \int_{1}^n \;  \frac{1}{x} \; dx   $$
$$ 1+ \int_2^{n+1} \; \frac{1}{x} \;  dx \;  < \; 1+ \sum_{j=2}^n \;  \frac{1}{j} \; < \; 1+ \int_{1}^n \;  \frac{1}{x} \; dx   $$
$$ 1+ \log (n+1) - \log 2 \;  < \;  \sum_{j=1}^n \;  \frac{1}{j} \; < \; 1+ \log n    $$